# Toolbar in Fragment crashes app on launch

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

This seems like a common issue with lots of accepted answers but none of them seem to be working for me.

Most answers suggest using this piece of code to add a toolbar into a fragment:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
```

Alas, this still crashes my app even though I'm using AppCompatActivity. I think the error may lie in the fact that my Fragment class extends Fragment and not AppCompatActivity but I don't know enough about android as of yet to be sure of this. It crashes on the setSupportActionBar line.

My Fragment code:

```
package erikligai.ribbitapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by erik on 2017-06-07.
 */

public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_fragment_layout, container, false);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_fragment_layout, container, false);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I assume that you have NullPointerException.
Why are you trying to put the Toolbar from the fragment view?

Comment: post your logcat.

Comment: Also, delegate the toolbar inflation to activity and not the fragment

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: erikligai.ribbitapplication.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: Why you have Choosing to do so on Fragment whereas you can do it in Activity Also, i suggest you, Define Your Toolbar in your Activity not in Fragment.

Comment: Even after defining it in my main activity, it still crashes the app on launch. All I'm doing now in the fragment is getting the toolbar from mainactivity and  setsupportactionbar. Is this still incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your activity from `getActivity()` to `AppCompatActivity`

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle();
```

`Toolbar` getting from `Activity`, not from `Fragment`

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```